# How to create and export an object made from multiple other object

Tags: edit-mode

I have found a freeware object (car tire) which I am trying to create another object made from 5 of this object.
The object is an .fbx object which I import into Blender, change the dimensions to actual dimensions of a tire, Set the Scale back to 1 (using ctrl A), rotate 90 degrees then duplicate the tyre 5 times then make slight modifications to 3 of those 5 objects (tires) so that they don't all look the same. The next object is displayed with correct material on each one.
I then export this object but when I import it into my Blender project each of the 5 tires has lost its texture/material and are displayed in a purple like color.

What am I doing wrong? I feel that there is one or more 'parameters' which need to be selected in the 'operator preset' panel but I don't know which ones.
Lastly what action gets rid of all the dimension values displayed (near the tires - see below)
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541

Comment: Duarte must love you. Whenever i asked a duplicate question he closes it within 1 minute.... ;)

Comment: When I entered the question (I wasn't sure how to word it or the correct phraseology) a number of suggested answers were displayed. NOT ONE answered my question. Maybe the 'search engine' isn't very smart?